# Bootstrap select the label when placeholder is not shown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In the example page for the floating label, there is a label selector for when the place holder is not shown:

```
.form-label-group input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ label {
  padding-top: calc(var(--input-padding-y) / 3);
  padding-bottom: calc(var(--input-padding-y) / 3);
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #777;
}
```

this selector is based on this HTML structure:

```
<div class="form-label-group">
   <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
   <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
</div>
```

I have a label with input which is in this structure:

```
<div id="" class="form-label-group ">
   <div class="form-before-field">
   </div>
   <div class="form-field">
      <div id="form-wrap" class="field-wrap" data-field-id="1">
         <div class="field-label">
            <label for="field-1" class="">Name </label>
         </div>
         <div class="field-element">
            <input type="text" value="" class="forms-field form-control" placeholder="Name" id="field-1" name="field-1" aria-invalid="false" aria-describedby="error-1">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="after-field">
      <section>
      <div class="input-limit"></div>
      <div id="error-1" class="error-wrap error" role="alert"></div>
      </section>
   </div>
</div>
```

what selector should I use to target the label when the place holder is not shown?

Answer (score 0):

## Specific question:

Due to your HTML structure, you would need to escape out of `<div class="field-element">` and then find the previous `<div class="field-label">`. And sadly, there is **neither** a **[parent selector](https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/)** nor a **['previous' selector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1817801/2341603)** in CSS. Therefore it is **impossible** to target your `<label>` based off of your placeholder's `<input>` using pure CSS.

Having said all that, I'll leave the more generic approach on this answer as well, because this is actually a fairly common request, and I'm sure someone will stumble on this question with a more traditional structure :)

---

## General targeting of `<label>`s based on `<input>` placeholders:

You might think that you could use the simple **[`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty)** pseudo-class for this, though unfortunately, that is not the case. This is because **[`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)** is a [**void element**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements), and as such, the content model is always empty.

The only pure CSS approach at the moment would be to make use of the **[`:placeholder-shown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:placeholder-shown)** pseudo-class. This can be combined with **[`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)** to target the `<input>` elements when the placeholder isn't present.

To target the corresponding **[`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)**, you can combine this with the **[adjacent sibling combinator (`+`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)** to target the label that comes immediately after the input.

So in summation, you're looking for:

```
input(:placeholder-shown) + label
```

Which can be seen in the following:

```css
input + label {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default for the sample */
}

input:not(:placeholder-shown) + label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input id="email" placeholder="Email">
<label for="email">Placeholder Not Shown!</label>
```

Note, however, that `:placeholder-shown` is currently [**not supported**](https://caniuse.com/#search=%3Aplaceholder-shown) in either Internet Explorer or Edge. Until those browsers add support for `:placeholder-shown`, you'll be forced to resort to a JavaScript solution.

Comment: fair enough, what if the label is before the input in your example?

Comment: The `<label>` **must** come after the `<input>`, and both elements **must** be a descendant of the same element. That is to say, you **cannot** target a parent in any way, and you **cannot** target a previous element in any way with pure CSS. With JavaScript you can use `.parentElement` and `.previousSibling` respectively, and then use `.style` if you need to apply styling rules.

Comment: so there is no way to target the label if it comes before the input? I was thinking of something like `label:has(input:not(:placeholder-shown))` but it doesnt work

Comment: It doesn't work because there is absolutely **no way of doing it**. Sorry, but it's true ;)

Comment: @RainMan Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector and https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-parent-selectors.